# Disable iPad "Screen Capture" function

Tags: ipad, screen, capture, printscreen

I'm building a program to handle sensitive data. I want to disable the "Screen Capture" function of iPad (press Home & On/Off buttons simultaneously).

Is there any method to do so?

Comment: I heard of a company that built a metal box to enclose the iPad to prevent that, so I'd guess "no, not programmatically" :D

Answer (score 3):

Nope. This is more or less a hardware feature in that it's uninterruptible.

Comment: thx jeff... is there any method to "re-map" this key combination?

Comment: No, but maybe if you jailbreak.